# Xubuntu "Bash" doent exist?

Tags: bash, scripts, xubuntu

Im having a problem with my xubuntu script. This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash/
cd /
touch ~/.config/zoomus.conf
cd ~/Desktop
'home/oem/Desktop/Zoom.desktop'
```

This is my error:

```
bash: ./zoom.sh: /bin/bash/^M: bad interpreter: Not a directory
```

Please help me fix this.
Im writing the script bc zoom wont run on here without the terminal. So im writing the script.

---

this is another error:

```
/home/oem/Desktop/Zoom.desktop: line 1: [Desktop: command not found
/home/oem/Desktop/Zoom.desktop: line 3: Video: command not found
/home/oem/Desktop/Zoom.desktop: line 4: fg: no job control
/home/oem/Desktop/Zoom.desktop: line 9: Application: command not found
/home/oem/Desktop/Zoom.desktop: line 11: x-scheme-handler/zoomus: No such file or directory
/home/oem/Desktop/Zoom.desktop: line 11: x-scheme-handler/tel: No such file or directory
/home/oem/Desktop/Zoom.desktop: line 11: x-scheme-handler/callto: No such file or directory
/home/oem/Desktop/Zoom.desktop: line 11: x-scheme-handler/zoomphonecall: No such file or directory
/home/oem/Desktop/Zoom.desktop: line 11: application/x-zoom: No such file or directory
/home/oem/Desktop/Zoom.desktop: line 12: X-KDE-Protocols=zoommtg: command not found
/home/oem/Desktop/Zoom.desktop: line 12: zoomus: command not found
/home/oem/Desktop/Zoom.desktop: line 12: tel: command not found
/home/oem/Desktop/Zoom.desktop: line 12: callto: command not found
/home/oem/Desktop/Zoom.desktop: line 12: zoomphonecall: command not found
```

Comment: Basically this:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it

Comment: Don't write linux scripts using Windows. ;-)

Comment: remove the last slash on the shebang it should be `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 8):

You have two problems:  (1) Carriage returns, and (2) incorrect paths.

**Carriage Returns**

Your script has extra carriage returns which are messing up handling of the script, because the system is trying to execute `/bin/bash^M` directly - which doesn't exist, because it can't; ultimately this is because you edited the script in Windows or wrote it in Windows.  This is commonly the case when you use Windows to make/edit Linux scripts.  So, don't create scripts in Windows that you intend to use on Linux.

That said, you can fix the problem.

Per [this post on our sister site Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it) you should try this specific solution:

- Use `dos2unix` to format the file better.

  1. Use `dos2unix /path/to/script`
  2. If that doesn't work, use `dos2unix -c mac /path/to/script`

At least one of these solutions should remove the `^M` carriage returns from the script and it SHOULD then work as expected.

**Fix your paths**

After you fix the carriage returns, `/bin/bash` is your executable, it's not a directory.  So your shebang line should be: `#!/bin/bash`

---

As for your Desktop errors (which needed to be added as an edit!):

use `exo-open /home/oem/Desktop/Zoom.desktop` to open the Desktop launcher file.

Comment: 1. im using xubuntu (im on linux rn) 2. That just deleted my file

Comment: which deleted the file?  You need to be specific what you're executing when commenting here.

Comment: i tryed the :%s/^M$//

Comment: @pugking ah, yeah, i just confirmed that's a little messed.  If you do `:q!` that will exit `vi` without saving and your file will be intact, so use `dos2unix`

Comment: error doing vi: E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name ".zoom.sh.swp"

Comment: Skip the `vi` entirely - just execute `:q!` when you're already inside of `vi` - if you've already closed `vi` and your script is back and intact, then only focus on `dos2unix` - you can remove the swp file with `rm .zoom.sh.swp`

Comment: ok. it removed the ^M BUT still says /bin/bash no file or dir

Comment: @pugking read the second part of my answer under "Fix your paths".  You've got `/bin/bash/` in your shebang line, not `/bin/bash`

Comment: You don't need Windows to get ^M at the end of lines. I had exactly this error the other day on kubuntu 20.08 using kwrite - with a new script file it defaulted to MS-DOS style line endings (a config option somewhere I'm sure.)

Comment: @B.Tanner When I've seen that behavior, it's because it detected that the file already had MS-DOS style line endings. But you can change it for the current file (Tools > End of line) or as a setting for the future (Settings > Configure Editor > Open/Save > End of line) or per file type.